# Deploy error message on WebLogic 10.3.6.0

Tags: oracle, deployment, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

After fresh install of web logic, deployment shows the error:

```
Message icon - Error Failed to load webapp: MyWebApp because of DeploymentException: 

weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for "ServletContext@992422938[app:MyWebApp module:MyWebApp path:/MyWebApp spec-version:2.5]", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: jsf, Specification-Version: 2, exact-match: false]

Error Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for "ServletContext@992422938[app:MyWebApp module:MyWebApp path:/MyWebApp 

spec-version:2.5]", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: jsf, Specification-Version: 2, exact-match: false]
```

I have Cloud service weblogic, initially is installed

- jsf(1.2,1.2.9.0) - [Name:jsf] [Specification Version:1.2] [Impl. Version: 1.2.9.0]
- jstl(1.2,1.2.0.1) [jstl, 1.2, 1.2.0.1]

When I try to install jsf-2.0.war - Error is
An application with this name already exists. Please specify a different name.

After I changed the name to something - Error is

```
The deployment has not been installed.
Message icon - Error weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Deployer:149105]An attempt was made to deploy a library located at '/u01/data/domains/wls_domain/servers/wls_adminserver/upload/jsf-2.0.war' with name 'jsf(2.0,1.0.0.0_2-0-2)' that is different from the one specified in the manifest of the library: 'jsf'.
```

Comment: Take a look at this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/web.1111/e13712/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP197) about how to install JSF 2 with WebLogic Server.

Comment: nothing to set in the classpath, just deploy jsf as a shared as explained in the documentation

Comment: Ok...I have updated jsf and now I have two jsf with same name (1.2 and 2.0)...now after deploy...NEW ERROR
Error Failed to load webapp:because App se of DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.view.faces.bi.webapp.MapProxyServlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web application requires the JSF 2 shared library which is not deployed in your server. Deploy this library first and then your application.

Comment: I have edited my questin, tried to install jsf 2.0 mannualy, but errors...

Comment: Ok...I have updated jsf and now I have two jsf with same name (1.2 and 2.0)...now after deploy...NEW ERROR Error Failed to load webapp:because App se of DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.view.faces.bi.webapp.MapProxyServlet

Comment: Ok, you should close this question and open another one for this new error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837046/deploy-adf-mapproxyservlet-error-weblogic-10-3-6-0  NEW QUESTION